# python 2.7 dnspython not resolving all urls when scripted

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a script to query A and CNAME records from a list. When I run the script it works, but it skips specific URLs. If I resolve the URLs one at a time from the interpreter, they return an A record fine. Python noob, please be gentle. Thanks!

Here's the code that's skipping some URLs:

```
from dns import resolver
import dns
import os
import csv
import time
errcountA = 0
errcountCNAME = 0
errcountCNAME2 = 0
list = []
combolist = []
sublist1 = open ("c:/temp/sublist2.txt", "r").read().replace('\r', '').splitlines()
print sublist1
print "\r\n"
print "there are %d total URLs in this list" %len(sublist1)
print "\r\n"
print "URLs being actually processed:"
for url in sublist1:
    A = []
    CNAME = []
    CNAME2 = []
    print "read %s prior to Resolver" %url.split()
    try:
        answer = dns.resolver.query(url, 'A', raise_on_no_answer=True)
        for rdata in answer:
            A.append(rdata.address)
            #time.sleep(1)
    except (dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN, dns.resolver.NoAnswer, dns.resolver.NoNameservers):
        A = "exception: DNS query name does not exist"
        errcountA += 1
        continue
    except dns.exception.Timeout:
        A = "exception: DNS query name does not exist"
        errcountA += 1
        continue
    except:
        A = "no IPV4 found"
        errcountA += 1
        continue
    try:
        answer = resolver.query(url, 'CNAME')
        for rdata in answer:
            CNAME.append(rdata.target)
    except:
        CNAME = "no CNAME found"
        errcountCNAME += 1
        continue
finally:
    list = [url, A, CNAME, CNAME2]
    combolist.append(list)
    print "read %s after Resolver" %url

with open("c:/temp/subsresolvedtest.csv", 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for r in combolist:
        writer.writerow(r)

print "\r\n"
print "URLs Resolved:"
print "\r\n"
print combolist
print "\r\n"
print ("There were %d 'A' record errors") %errcountA
print "\r\n"
print ("There were %d CNAME record errors") %errcountCNAME
print "\r\n"
print ("There were %d nested CNAME record errors") %errcountCNAME2
print "\r\n"
print ("Done")
```

But if I run the skipped URLs individually from the interpreter, they resolve and return an A record fine:

```
answer = dns.resolver.query("actual_website_URL", 'A')
for rdata in answer:
    print(rdata.address)

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx #an actual IP address is returned which matches ping/nslookup etc.
```

Running individual queries with the following also works (and I would prefer it), but I have been unable to figure out the formatting to make it iterate through an list without returning an "'list' object has no attribute 'is_absolute'" error:

```
import dns.resolver
name = 'iana.org'
for qtype in 'A', 'AAAA', 'MX', 'NS', 'TXT', 'SOA':
    answer = dns.resolver.query(name,qtype, raise_on_no_answer=False)
    if answer.rrset is not None:
        print(answer.rrset)
```

Again, I'm extremely new with this and appreciate any assistance. Thanks!